# mutt: ask for confirmation before moving message to archive

Tags: email, mutt, macro

I have following macro defined in my `muttrc`:

```
macro  index s ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes auto_tag=yes\n\
    <save-message>=archive\n<sync-mailbox>:set delete=ask-yes\n"
```

When I press `s` on a message, it will immediately be moved into my `archive` folder.

I would like to modify my macro, so that I will be asked for confirmation before the message is moved.

But when I change `confirmappend=yes`:

```
macro index s ":set confirmappend=yes delete=yes auto_tag=yes\n\
    <save-message>=archive\n<sync-mailbox>:set delete=ask-yes\n"
```

and when I press `s`, mutt becomes immediately unresponsive, all keys stop working, I cannot even exit. The cpu runs at 100% and I have to log in from another console to kill mutt.

Can somebody please advise how to correctly modify my macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the \n from after the folder name so the command you are looking for is

```
macro  index s ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes auto_tag=yes\n\
<save-message>=archive<sync-mailbox>:set delete=ask-yes\n"
```